# Laravel query on Many to Many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have an API to keep tracked photos and tags. Each photo can have N tags and one tag can be linked to N photos. That's done using 3 tables:

- Photo's table.
- Tag's table.
- photo_tag relation table.

Now I'm working to get all photos tagged with a set of tags the idea is to make requests to my API with a list of tags and get a list of photos that has at least all the tags.

I've been trying with the `whereIn` operator.

This is my code (now it's all hardcoded):

```
$photos = Photo::whereHas('tags', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->whereIn('tag', ['a5', 'mate', 'Brillante']);
        })->get();

        return response()->json($photos, 200);
```

When I execute it it return all that photos that match one tag and I need only photos that hast all the requested tags (in this example a5, mate).

I'm working on Laravel 9.

Edit:

As Tim Lewis suggested I've tried looping:

```
$tags = array("a5", "mate", "Brilante");
        $photoQuery = Photo::query();

        foreach($tags as $tag) {
            \Log::debug($tag);
            $photoQuery->whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tag) {
                return $query->where('tag', $tag);
            });
        }

        $photos = $photoQuery->get();
```

Now it's returning an empty list I think because is looking for Photos that only have the 3 tags I hardcoded on the array.

Edit 2:

It seems that those changes were right, but for some reason Postman was not showing me any results of those changes are the solutions to my issue.

Comment: `whereIn()` matches against any of the options, not all of the options. If you need to match against all, you probably need 3 `whereHas()` clauses, each checking a single tag.

Comment: This is meant to work as API and I don't know how many tags my users will send me on each request is there other approach?

Comment: That can still work; you just use a loop to add `whereHas()` clauses dynamically. I see that you said you have this hard-coded at the moment, but it is not difficult to make that dynamic.

Comment: Ok, I try looping as you suggest

Comment: Try with assignment as well: `$photoQuery = $photoQuery->whereHas(...);`. Also, check your spelling; `Brillante` vs `Brilante`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `whereIn()` method matches against *any* of the values provided, and not *all*, you'll need to modify this. Specificying a number of `whereHas()` clauses, 1 for each Tag, should work:

```php
$photoQuery = Photo::query();
foreach ($request->input('tags') as $tag) {
  $photoQuery = $photoQuery->whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tag) {
    return $query->where('tag', $tag);
  });
}
$photos = $photoQuery->get();
```

Now, depending on the `tags` being sent to your API (assuming through the `$request` variable as a `'tags' => []` array), this query will include a `whereHas()` clause for each Tag, and only return `Photo` records that have all specified Tags.

Comment: I've tried and it's returning an empty list I think it's because is looking for Photos with only the 3 tags I've specified? It should bring me all the photos with at least this 3 tags or more. I'm going to add this new code to the original question.

Comment: Have you manually checked that the tags your sending are applied to at least 1 Photo? This code shouldn't care if there are other, unspecified tags attached; as long as all of the Tags you sent are included, it should return info. Maybe adjust your question to include a DB screenshot of the tags, their ids and association in the DB.

Comment: Also, try replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` to see what query is actually being executed.

Comment: Now is working I think it was something on postman. Thank you Tim!

Comment: Nice syntax, seems like legible code. It use impedance concepts (databases)?

Comment: @Whats91356Java Thanks, that's just Laravel's syntax for "Eloquent" queries using defined Models and Relationships. I don't have a computer science or database admin background, so I'm not sure what "impedance concepts" is in this context.